# Whats the meaning of 'static get' in Javascript (ES6)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to now whats the meaning of an expression like this in Javascript

```
static get is() { return "custom-element"; }
```

I guess that `static` can have a behaviour similar to Java or C++ but I need more information about these syntax.

Comment: Generally when you want to find out more information about syntax, you can Google it first. I would recommend doing that first, and then asking here if something is unclear.

Comment: Example: I used `static get send() { throw new this; }` in a `class ValueError extends Error`. What this does, is, when I call `ValueError.send`, it is equivalent to `throw new ValueError()`. Here's what happens: `get`makes it so I don't have to use `()` after send.  static makes it so I don't have to use `new` and `()` after ValueError. Also, in case you're wondering, `throw new this` is equivalent to `throw new ValueError`, and this works because `ValueError` is an `instanceof` `Error`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You are correct. They are ***pretty much close*** to any other object oriented programming languages like C++ and Java

Everything is documented. That is a static method you are looking at and the get is a `getter` for the property or the Object you want to get.

If you look at [***explore static***](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_classes.html)

> **static methods**. Static properties (or class properties) are properties of Foo itself. If you prefix a method definition with static, you create a class method:

```
> typeof Foo.staticMethod
'function'
> Foo.staticMethod()
'classy'
```

And  ***static*** property:

I can't think a great example than given in docs on top of my head right now. Here i am pasting essential part.

```
class Point {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

Point.ZERO = new Point(0, 0);
```

You could use Object.defineProperty() to create a read-only property, but I like the simplicity of an assignment.

Second, you can create a static getter:

```
class Point {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    static get ZERO() {
        return new Point(0, 0);
    }
}
```

In both cases, you get a property Point.ZERO that you can read. In the first case, the same instance is returned every time. In the second case, a new instance is returned every time.

Comment: I would be very careful with that first sentence. The syntax is similar, and that's about all there is in common. A `class` in JS is just syntactic sugar for a constructor function with a `prototype`.

Comment: @4castle I'm scared. `Static properties (or class properties) are properties of Foo itself. If you prefix a method definition with static, you create a class method:` this applies to Java as well. Correct me if I am wrong with any sentence.

Comment: That's all correct, but assuming JS will behave like Java is dangerous. For example, in JS, `static` properties are inherited by the functions which `extend` the original function, also objects which inherit from `Foo.prototype` will not have access to the `static` method like they would using Java syntax. I find that people who use `class` syntax don't take the time to learn the "old-fashioned" way to do things, and they end up using classes in inappropriate ways.

Comment: @4castle That is the reason I said that the pretty much and not completely :) and I have to agree  with your last sentence completely.